# Top tools for c#/sql developer

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I love resharper it makes refactoring other peoples code also most fun.
www.jetbrains.com/resharper
And ghost doc is another great tool.

http://submain.com/GhostDoc

I would love to use redgates sql prompt but my company wont pay for it ? so free tools are the best :)

My question is what other great tool are in the c#/sql dev toolbar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find a lot goodies by reading [Scott Hanselman's tool list](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2009UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx).

Other tools I would ad to that list:

- [Snippet Compiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/)
- [The Regex Coach](http://the-regex-coach.en.softonic.com/)

Answer (score 2):

These links should be helpful:

- [Tools and techniques to optimize a LINQ to SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389930/tools-and-techniques-to-optimize-a-linq-to-sql-query/1390046#1390046)
- [Blog post of LINQ tools](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/LINQ-Tools) (mentioned in the above post)
- [The .NET SDK Programs - What does each tool do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362687/the-net-sdk-programs-what-does-each-tool-do)

You may have also heard of [CodeRush/Refactor! Pro](http://devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/), which is a tool similar to ReSharper.

I like the [Expresso tool](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) for regular expressions. I have a few regex references in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392009/how-to-show-which-sub-regex-failed-to-match/1392066#1392066).

Comment: hmm you must do alot of linq.

Sadly for some BS reason we are not allowed to use link, somthing to do with dynmic sql :(

Comment: That's unfortunate. There's more to it than just LINQ to SQL though, specifically in-memory objects and XML.

Answer (score 1):

- A file management program: Total Commander
- for screenshot, on Vista, Snipping Tool (there is a free program for XP that is quite similar)